# Installing R with homebrew with java support

Tags: java, r, osx-lion, homebrew

I have been trying to install the R language with homebrew but when I install java packages like iplots I get the following error:

```
* installing *source* package ‘iplots’ ...
** R
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices ...
** testing if installed package can be loaded
Note: On Mac OS X we strongly recommend using iplots from within JGR.
Proceed at your own risk as iplots cannot resolve potential ev.loop deadlocks.
'Yes' is assumed for all dialogs as they cannot be shown without a deadlock,
also ievent.wait() is disabled.
2012-01-29 16:24:57.870 R[29384:c07] Apple AWT Java VM was loaded on first thread -- can't start AWT.
Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'iplots', details:
  call: .jnew("org/rosuda/iplots/Framework")
  error: java.lang.InternalError: Can't start the AWT because Java was started on the first thread.  Make sure StartOnFirstThread is not specified in your application's Info.plist or on the command line
Error: loading failed
Execution halted
ERROR: loading failed
* removing ‘/Users/User/Library/R/2.14/library/iplots’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘iplots’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘iplots’ is not available for package ‘JGR’
* removing ‘/Users/User/Library/R/2.14/library/JGR’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘JGR’ had non-zero exit status
```

I have been told that R needs to be installed with the following command `NOAWT=1 R CMD INSTALL ...`  I'm not entirely sure how to do this with homebrew.

I tried using this `brew install r --NOAWT=1` with no luck.

Any help would be much appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Off-topic for SO; not a question about programming; possibly belongs on superuser.com.  If you were hacking/modifying the brew installer and had this error, then the question would be appropriate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you install R from homebrew R is compiled from source.  To install something like iplots where you get this error you need to use the following command from the R console:

```
Sys.setenv(NOAWT=1)
```

You may need to remove this afterwords in which case you can use this:

```
Sys.unsetenv("NOAWT")
```